# Maximize windows every Xth minute

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, timer

I am developing a C# desktop application. I want my all open windows to pop up (something which happens with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>) every 5th minute. I looked at a few questions here. They suggest doing it by using timers, but how do I pop up the minimised windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a really basic example for you to work on.

1. First create the timer.
2. Create a function that will run when the timer ticks.
3. Then add an event to run every time it ticks. And link it your function
4. Inside that function check if it has been 5 minutes. If so, maximize
   the window

   ```
   public partial class TimerForm : Form
   {
       Timer timer = new Timer();
       Label label = new Label();

       public TimerForm ()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); // Everytime timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
           timer.Interval = (1000) * (1);              // Timer will tick evert second
           timer.Enabled = true;                       // Enable the timer
           timer.Start();                              // Start the timer
       }

       void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
             // HERE you check if five minutes have passed or whatever you like!

             // Then you do this on your window.
             this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int formCount = 0;
    int X = 10;
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); // Everytime timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
        timer.Interval = (1000) * X;                // Timer will tick evert second
        timer.Enabled = true;                       // Enable the timer
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormCollection fc = new FormCollection();
        fc = Application.OpenForms;

        foreach (Form Z in fc)
        {
            X = X + 5;
            formCount++;
            if (formCount == fc.Count)
                X = 5;

            Z.TopMost = true;
            Z.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```